# DocuSign text fields are sharing the same values when they should not

Tags: json, docusignapi

I have a custom contract where we have some text fields set in place, but for reasons not immediately known, the text value for these fields is joined -- I alter one field, the other alters as well (you can see the behavior in this video [here](https://vid.me/vfb3)). There are distinct tags being used for each instance (these are set in the PDF file sent upstream, as the tag #EREM{NUM}). Am I missing something in my JSON request for these text fields?

The JSON request transmitted is posted below.

```
{
"status": "sent",
"emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document",
"documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "Signed Contract 2016-11-11 16:27:34"
}],
"recipients": {
    "signers": [{
        "email": "XXX@YYY.com",
        "name": "Sales Agent",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#ESIG0",
                "anchorXOffset": 10,
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "initialHereTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EINIT0",
                "anchorXOffset": "10",
                "anchorYOffset": "45",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "checkBoxTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#ECHK00",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK00"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK01",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK01"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK02",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK02"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK03",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK03"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK04",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK04"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK05",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK05"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK06",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK06"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK07",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK07"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK08",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK08"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK09",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK09"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK10",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK10"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK11",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK11"
            }],
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EDATE_0",
                "anchorXOffset": "20",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "textTabs": [],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 0",
                "radios": []
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "email": "JZ@REDFZ.com",
        "name": "Cameron Kilgore",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#ESIG_1",
                "anchorXOffset": 10,
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "initialHereTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EINIT_1",
                "anchorXOffset": "10",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "checkBoxTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#ECHK00",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK00"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK01",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK01"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK02",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK02"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK03",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK03"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK04",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK04"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK05",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK05"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK06",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK06"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK07",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK07"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK08",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK08"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK09",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK09"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK10",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK10"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK11",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK11"
            }],
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EDATE_1",
                "anchorXOffset": "10",
                "anchorYOffset": "-5",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EREM0",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "locked": "false",
                "value": "",
                "required": "false",
                "width": 250
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#EREM1",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "locked": "false",
                "required": "false",
                "value": "",
                "width": 250
            }],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 1",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_1_YES_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_1_YES_OWNER",
                    "tabLabel": "Explanation0"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_1_NO_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_1_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 2",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_2_YES_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_2_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_2_NO_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_2_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 3",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_3_YES_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_3_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_3_NO_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_3_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 4",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_4_YES_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_4_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_4_NO_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_4_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 5",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_5_YES_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_5_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_5_NO_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_5_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 6",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_6_YES_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_6_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_6_NO_OWNER_1",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_6_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "email": "XY@ZZY.com",
        "name": "Cameron Kilgore",
        "recipientId": "3",
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#ESIG_2",
                "anchorXOffset": 10,
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "initialHereTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EINIT_2",
                "anchorXOffset": "10",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "checkBoxTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#ECHK12",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK12"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK13",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK13"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK14",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK14"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK15",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK15"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK16",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK16"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK17",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK17"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK18",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK18"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK19",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK19"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK20",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK20"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK21",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK21"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK22",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK22"
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#ECHK23",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "tabLabel": "ECHK23"
            }],
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EDATE_2",
                "anchorXOffset": "10",
                "anchorYOffset": "-5",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "anchorString": "#EREM2",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "locked": "false",
                "required": "false",
                "width": 250
            }, {
                "anchorString": "#EREM3",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                "locked": "false",
                "required": "false",
                "width": 250
            }],
            "radioGroupTabs": [{
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 1",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_1_YES_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_1_YES_OWNER",
                    "tabLabel": "Explanation2"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_1_NO_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_1_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 2",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_2_YES_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_2_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_2_NO_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_2_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 3",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_3_YES_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_3_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_3_NO_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_3_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 4",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_4_YES_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_4_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_4_NO_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_4_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 5",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_5_YES_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_5_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_5_NO_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_5_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }, {
                "documentId": "1",
                "groupName": "Radio Group 6",
                "radios": [{
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_6_YES_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_6_YES_OWNER"
                }, {
                    "anchorString": "#RADIO_6_NO_OWNER_2",
                    "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true",
                    "value": "RADIO_6_NO_OWNER"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Set the tabs' `tabId` fields to have unique values to stop one tab's value being used for all of the tabs.